# Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '::' token

Tags: c++

I get the below error when compiling my file.

```
//Error
PluginDiskstats.cpp:107: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '::' token
scons: *** [PluginDiskstats.o] Error 1



// destructor
~PluginDiskstats::PluginDiskstats() // line 107
{
    if (stream != NULL) {
        fclose(stream);
        stream = NULL;
    }
    hash_destroy(&DISKSTATS);
}



// header file

#ifndef __PLUGIN_DISKSTATS_H__
#define __PLUGIN_DISKSTATS_H__

#include <QObject>
#include "Hash.h"

class PluginDiskstats : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    HASH DISKSTATS;
    FILE *stream;
    int ParseDiskstats();

    public:
    PluginDiskstats();
    ~PluginDiskstats();

    public slots:
    double Diskstats(QString arg1, QString arg2, double arg3);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change line 107 to:

```
PluginDiskstats::~PluginDiskstats()
```

Comment: /facepalm Man can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks.